# Abel's Functional Equation for $L(x) = \sum x^{n}/n^{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

In *"Ramanujan: Twelve Lectures on Subjects Suggested by His Life and Work"* Hardy talks of Abel's Functional Equation $$L(x) + L(y) + L(xy) + L\left(\frac{x(1 - y)}{1 - xy}\right) + L\left(\frac{y(1 - x)}{1 - xy}\right) = 3L(1)$$ for the function $$L(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}} = \frac{x}{1^{2}} + \frac{x^{2}}{2^{2}} + \frac{x^{3}}{3^{2}} + \cdots$$ But if we put $x = y = 0$ and note that $L(0) = 0, L(1) = \pi^{2}/6$ the functional equation seems wrong. Perhaps there is some typo in the book or maybe the formula is valid only for $0 < x, y < 1$. Do we have any information available on $L(x)$ and its functional equation? A proof of the same would be much appreciated.

Comment: the identity I know is $R(x) + R(y) = R(xy) + R\left(\frac{x(1 - y)}{1 - xy}\right) + R\left(\frac{y(1 - x)}{1 - xy}\right)$ where $R(x)=L(x)+\frac{1}{2}\log x\,\log(1-x)$, true for $0<x,y<1$ ($R$ is called Roger's dilogarithm)

Comment: Ok I will try to use the relation for $R(x)$ and try to see what it says for $L(x)$.